# JQuery selector for a class but only next item

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am not to sure how to select my the div class="Repors_comments_form".
Here how it looks

```
<div>
  <span onclick ="$('.Reports_comments_form').toggle();"  style="cursor:pointer">Report</span>
</div>
<div class="Reports_comments_form">
</div><!-- End of div Reports_form -->
```

It is important to note that this is in a loop, has there can be many comments and would like only the next one. I have try many ways but all i can do is grab all class element.

I have try

```
<span onclick ="$('.Reports_comments_form').toggle();"
<span onclick ="$('.Reports_comments_form').toggle().next();"
<span onclick ="$('.Reports_comments_form').next().toggle();"
<span onclick ="$('.Reports_comments_form').closest('div').next().toggle();"
```

Comment: Use `id`s. And don't use intrusive javascript [i.e. `onclick` attribute].

Comment: Give those ids and then grab using that specific id

Comment: why are you mixing inline script and jQuery? Defeats the purpose of using an unobtrusive script library

Comment: I am using rails, and its on an actions, not sure how to have it unobtructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a class to the span you can remove your inline script completely and use unobtrusive jQuery clcik handler:

HTML

```
<div>
  <span class="reportButton" style="cursor:pointer">Report</span>
</div>
<div class="Reports_comments_form">
```

JS

```
 /* uses next() assuming you may have this button and report sequence in page multiple times*/
$(function(){
    $('.reportButton').click(function(){
              $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    })
})
```

If buttons are added dynamically after page load can delegate the clcik handler using `on()`

Answer (score 2):

To keep the behavior consistent without messing with `parent()` chains:

**Markup:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-target="someId" class="reportButton">Report</a>
</div>
<div id="someId" class="report">

      // you'll be generating the id in the loop, e.g. 'report-12', 'report-13' and so on

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.reportButton').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault()

    $('#' + $(this).data('target') ).toggle()

})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <span onclick ="$(this).parent().next().toggle();"  style="cursor:pointer">Report</span>
</div>
<div class="Reports_comments_form">
    adadadads
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span onclick ="$(this).parent().next('.Reports_comments_form').toggle();"
```